# Pass multiple data from one function to label in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, amazon-web-services

I have a function that retrieves multiple lines of data and I want to display them in a label. My function is as shown below.

```
public static string GetItemByQuery(IAmazonSimpleDB simpleDBClient, string domainName)
    {

        SelectResponse response = simpleDBClient.Select(new SelectRequest()
        {
            SelectExpression = "Select * from " + domainName
        });
        String res = domainName + " has: ";

        foreach (Item item in response.Items)
        {
            res = item.Name + ": ";
            foreach (Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute attribute in item.Attributes)
            {
                res += "{" + attribute.Name + ", " + attribute.Value + "}, ";
            }
            res = res.Remove(res.Length - 2);


        }

        return res;
    }
```

So far I can only return a string which is the last line of the retrieved data. How can I retrieve all the records? I tries arraylist, but it seems that the AWS web application doesn't allow me to use arraylist. Can anyone please help me to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return it as as a Enumberable,

```
List<String> Results ;
```

Your method would be

```
public static List<String> GetItemByQuery(IAmazonSimpleDB simpleDBClient, string domainName)
    {
       List<String> Results = null;
        SelectResponse response = simpleDBClient.Select(new SelectRequest()
        {
            SelectExpression = "Select * from " + domainName
        });
        String res = domainName + " has: ";

        foreach (Item item in response.Items)
        {
            Results = new List<String>();
            res = item.Name + ": ";
            foreach (Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute attribute in item.Attributes)
            {
                res += "{" + attribute.Name + ", " + attribute.Value + "}, ";
            }
            res = res.Remove(res.Length - 2);
            Results.Add(res);
        }

        return Results;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Instead of using console.printout, Any suggestion on UI control to display Results?